# Using a variable after getscript not working

Tags: jquery, scope, constants, getscript

I am trying to use a variable after I have included a script, but it is saying that the variable "PHP_MODULE_ROOT is not defined, when it is.

```
$.getScript("../IMS3/assets/js/globals.js") ;
const CONTROLER = PHP_MODULE_ROOT+'/manageContact.php' ;
```

The code in global.js is:

```
var SYSTEM_ROOT = 'http://place.mysite.com/IMS3' ;  // The system root, this needs to be changed if you move the system.

var ASSETS_ROOT = SYSTEM_ROOT+'/assets' ;       // The root for all things like JS and PHP
var JS_MODULE_ROOT = ASSETS_ROOT+'/js/modules' ;    // The JS modules like dialog boxes and widgets etc.
var PHP_MODULE_ROOT = ASSETS_ROOT+'/php/modules' ;
```

I have tried putting the const declaration as the callback declaration in $.getScript, but I get the same result.